# How to replace Frontend DB while open with a new version

Tags: ms-access, replace, frontend, version

I am trying to automate the replacement of the frontend with a new version, but I am not sure how to replace it since I am currently working in it.  This is for users of the system, so I want it as seamless as possible.

Thanks!  --Eddi Rae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have used in the past is to create a short-cut on the user's desktop. This runs a DOS .BAT file that copies the front-end from the server. When you have a new version to be released, you copy your version (after compacting and repairing) into this location. When the user opens the application the next time, it will automatically copy over the latest version. As a slight bonus, each time they start the application it will be "fresh", so will not need compacting on close.

If it is urgent that all users switch over to the latest version, then you could send them an email to restart the application. You could also write some VBA to update the user's version number in a table in the back-end, so you can see who hasn't restarted.

When I place a new version on the server to be rolled out, I will place the old version into a sub-folder, renamed with the version number, so that it is easy to roll-back to the previous version if required.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for sharing!! I think that I can incorporate in what I am doing.

Comment: Applecore, I understand your concept, but If you open the application (FE database), how can you then copy with the same name when you have it open?

Comment: The shortcut that the user clicks on to start the application is a BAT file that does two things. Firstly, it copies over a "clean" version from the server to a location on their PC on the C:\ drive. Secondly, it opens the copied FE database up.

Comment: Just to let you know, I pull the latest version from an FTP because we have several companies that are using the software. The file name has the version in it.  Once I copy it down, I want to change the links to match their folder for the BackEnd.  Also, in the batch file that you suggest, I don't want to have to repull every time once I pull it down to the local machine.  What would you suggest to get this done

Comment: Look at using a table to store the connection string in, and then relinking the tables when the application is started up.If several companies are using the software, then you may want to get them to put the BE onto a folder on one of their servers, and getting a scheduled task to run hourly to get the latest version from the FTP site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final file without my actual filenames

```
@echo off

SET varUpdaterFolder=%CD%\Updaters\FileVer*.accdr
SET varUpdaterFile=%CD%\Updaters\File.accdr
SET varFinalFile=%CD%\File.accdr

if exist "%varUpdaterFile%" (goto StartFile)
if not exist "%varUpdaterFolder%" (goto :StartFile)

:UpdateFile
for %%c in ("%varUpdaterFolder%") do (copy "%%c" "%varUpdaterFile%")
del "%varFinalFile%"
copy "%varUpdaterFile%" "%varFinalFile%"

:StartFile
REM timeout /t -1
start File.accdr
```

Thanks again for all your help!!